# Android emulator does not have eth0 when checked using adb shell ifconfig

Tags: android, android-emulator, ip, adb

I am following a set of instruction of how to check emulator ip (should be 10.0.2.15).

The instruction is simple

> adb shell
>   ifconfig eth0

However I get bellow error.

> ifconfig: eth0: No such device

doing ifconfig -a give bellow devices

```
generic_x86:/ $ ifconfig
radio0    Link encap:UNSPEC
          inet addr:192.168.200.2  Bcast:192.168.200.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fec0::c85f:8d1e:6e52:3f14/64 Scope: Site
          inet6 addr: fec0::7854:d4ff:fe56:b633/64 Scope: Site
          inet6 addr: fe80::7854:d4ff:fe56:b633/64 Scope: Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:725 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:728 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:97723 TX bytes:73200

wlan0     Link encap:UNSPEC    Driver mac80211_hwsim
          inet addr:192.168.232.2  Bcast:192.168.239.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ff:fe44:5566/64 Scope: Link
          inet6 addr: fec0::bcd4:4637:9032:f4cc/64 Scope: Site
          inet6 addr: fec0::ff:fe44:5566/64 Scope: Site
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:96591 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:40225 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:132047321 TX bytes:3916668

lo        Link encap:UNSPEC
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope: Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1075 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1075 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:76576 TX bytes:76576
```

Is any of them etho (hence having 10.0.2.15 ip address? I don't think so!) or eth0 is not there and how to add it, enable it or troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You are using a higher version of android API (>= 25). I think eth0 is in namespace router of your emulator. API <= 24 are using eth0 to simulate cellular network, so you could find it by typing `ifconfig` directly. API >= 25's eth0 is in namespace `router`, you could find it by typing `execns router ifconfig`

Answer (score 0):

Just after asking this question I found a solution. It is a workaround and does not really answer this question. But might help others that are stuck with similar problem.

Rather than accessing that 10.0.2.15 ip (that is missing because no eth0). We can forward android emulator port to the development machine ip (which is local ip or localhost or 127.0.0.1).

Execute bellow command in the development machine cmd prompt or console (and not inside adb shell).

> adb forward tcp: tcp:

or in my case I successfully visit localhost:20202 by doing bellow command

> adb forward tcp:20202 tcp:8080

For those who are wondering why I have http server running in my Android emulator. It is because I am playing around with [NanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd)